# Engine, sudden reduced power with soft shaking

Tags: engine, power, turbocharger, shaking, acceleration

I have a 2007 Holden with a 2.0 Turbo engine. On one day I decided to go through a light that had just turned orange- so I pressed down, not completely as I new how much power I needed to go through the intersection. Surprisingly very little power was produced, as if I was two gears higher than I should be. Then I noticed the power (the little it was producing) was not smooth- the engine was shaky. Next thing I noticed the engine sign was flashing. So I parked for a few minutes checking the engine area which looked fine. Started the car again and engine sign was gone. Now I feel the shaking only when I try to accelerate faster that normal, the shaking is very light. What could be wrong with the vehicle? And yes I am taking it for a checkup in a few days.

Comment: First thing I'd do is get the computer scanned so you can see what code popped when the CEL came on. This would probably tell you a whole bunch.

Comment: It sounds like your car's struggling to deliver fuel at high loads. How's the fuel pump? Possible vacuum leak? As Paulster2 said, retrieving the codes should help you hone in on the problem

Comment: I am taking the vehicle in for service and check up on that issue tomorrow. I will certainly get back here and update you guys!

Comment: So the guys at holden replaced spark plugs and ignition coil. Vehicle feels and sounds great now! Not sure if I should place this as an answer...

Comment: Please put you last comment here as the answer so we can button this question up! I'm glad you got it running right :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have checked the plugs and coil(s), but looks like you already found that answer.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened to me. all of a sudden, less power and engine vibration. Like the car did not want to go into third gear. When i went over 60 kms/hour the engine light came on. Straight to my mechanic, he only found the problem next day when the car did not even start. Basically a wet battery too low on water. Only cost me a dollar and the car has been fine since. Hope this info might help somebody someday.